# PGFplots: Calculate the title rotation angle to make it parallel to the visibly longer axis

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot

In order to make the title parallel to the visibly longer axis, how is it possible to calculate the rotation angles of both titles (i.e. `\FirstTitleAngle` and `\SecondTitleAngle`) instead of the manual trial?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\FirstTitleAngle}{5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title=some long long long  title,
        view={75}{30},
        title style={rotate=\FirstTitleAngle}
        ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            domain=-2:2,
            domain y=-1.3:1.3,
            ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newcommand{\SecondTitleAngle}{-3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title=some long long long  title,
    view={-80}{20},
    title style={rotate=\SecondTitleAngle}
    ]
    \addplot3 [
    surf,
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=-1.3:1.3,
    ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additionally, for groupplots, in case of global `view={}{}`, how can the angle be calculated and assigned globally?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group name=G,
    group size=2 by 3,
}, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty, view={75}{30}
]
\nextgroupplot[title=some long long long ong title]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=some long long long ong title]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>What `title` does for you is to place a node with that content on the axis shape. If you are willing to do that with Ti*k*Z, you could compute the angle with the `calc` library. You will still have to decide yourself whether you want the title be parallel to the x- or y-axis, which dictates the choice of the coordinate `x1`, and in some direction differs by 180 degrees from the natural choice, which is why there is a `-180` in the second example.</s> Forget about all this, please. Here come two styles that determine the rotation angles of the x- and y-axis, respectively.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{find y axis rotation/.style={
before end axis/.code={\path (0,0,0) coordinate (x0) (0,1,0) coordinate (x1);
\path let
\p1=($(x1)-(x0)$),\n1={ifthenelse(\x1>0,atan2(\y1,\x1),atan2(\y1,\x1)-180)} in 
\pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n1}};}
},
find x axis rotation/.style={
before end axis/.code={\path (0,0,0) coordinate (x0) (1,0,0) coordinate (x1);
\path let
\p1=($(x1)-(x0)$),\n1={ifthenelse(\x1>0,atan2(\y1,\x1),atan2(\y1,\x1)-180)} in 
\pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n1}};}
},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title=some long long long  title,
        view={75}{30},
        find y axis rotation=\myangle,
        title style={rotate=\myangle}
        ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            domain=-2:2,
            domain y=-1.3:1.3,
            ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        find y axis rotation=\myangle,
        title=some long long long  title,
        view={-80}{20},
        title style={rotate=\myangle} 
    ]
    \addplot3 [
    surf,
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=-1.3:1.3,
    ] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for your question on group plots: it works just the same.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathtools}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{find y axis rotation/.style={
before end axis/.code={\path (0,0,0) coordinate (x0) (0,1,0) coordinate (x1);
\path let
\p1=($(x1)-(x0)$),\n1={ifthenelse(\x1>0,atan2(\y1,\x1),atan2(\y1,\x1)-180)} in 
\pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n1}};}
},
find x axis rotation/.style={
before end axis/.code={\path (0,0,0) coordinate (x0) (1,0,0) coordinate (x1);
\path let
\p1=($(x1)-(x0)$),\n1={ifthenelse(\x1>0,atan2(\y1,\x1),atan2(\y1,\x1)-180)} in 
\pgfextra{\xdef#1{\n1}};}
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group name=G,
    group size=2 by 3,
}, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty, view={75}{30}
]
\nextgroupplot[title=some long long long ong title,
find y axis rotation=\myangle,title style={rotate=\myangle}]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
%
\nextgroupplot[title=some long long long ong title,
find y axis rotation=\myangle,title style={rotate=\myangle}]
\addplot3 [
surf,
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-1.3:1.3,
] {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I would like to understand the different types of the coordinate systems (e.g. `axis cs` or `rel cs`), so could you kindly refer me to the respective section in the manual?

Comment: Your update is perfect. One final touch; if I have groupplosts, and I set the `view={}{}` globally for all the plots inside the group options, what would be different in this case in your code?

Comment: I edited my question to include an MWE of groupplots with global `view={}{}`.

Comment: @Diaa I further simplified the code. No more adding -180. As for the `current axis` object, if you follow the link in the pgfplots manual, you'll get directed to section 4.20, but I cannot find much useful info there. I cannot search for `current axis`, i.e. with a blank between the words, can you?

Comment: You did an amazing job by responding to all my inquiries. I couldn't be more grateful. I will look for what you mentioned and get back in case I lost my road `:)`. Many thanks!

Comment: @Diaa *Now* I can search for expressions. At least for preview (Mac OS) the following works: just put the stuff in `"`, i.e. search for `"current axis"`. (Not that I was overwhelmed by what I found... ;-)